# Material Ui label breaking in Select component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

i have been trying to implement a select component, nothing as I have ever done before,
But suddenly my mui-select component is breaking, Below is the image of the bug/issue i am facing

[image]

The label of the select element is no longer in sync with the select component itself
Here is the code:

```
                           <FormControl size="small" fullWidth>
                                    <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-helper">
                                        Marital Status
                                    </InputLabel>
                                    <Select
                                        labelId="demo-simple-select-helper"
                                        id="demo-simple-select-helper"
                                        label="Marital Status"
                                        defaultValue=""
                                        {...getFieldProps('pf.maritalStatus')}
                                    >
                                        <MenuItem value="married">Married</MenuItem>
                                        <MenuItem value="unmarried">Unmarried</MenuItem>
                                        <MenuItem value="widow">Widow</MenuItem>
                                        <MenuItem value="widower">Widower</MenuItem>
                                        <MenuItem value="divorcee">Divorcee</MenuItem>
                                    </Select>
                                </FormControl>
```

Is there anything wrong i am doing here?

Here is the snippet used in the [mui](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/#basic-select) docs

```
<FormControl fullWidth>
  <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
  <Select
    labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
    id="demo-simple-select"
    value={age}
    label="Age"
    onChange={handleChange}
  >
    <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Please can anyone tell what's wrong i am doing here?

Comment: Are you setting the value onChange ?

Comment: @OrçunGüler yes, getFieldProps() returns all those properties such as value, name and onChange required for controlled form

Comment: Might be that both InputLabel and Select have the same id. In the mui snippet the ids are different.

Comment: @Felix tried changing that too, but no luck

Comment: Try changing {...getFieldProps('pf.maritalStatus')} to initiatProps={...getFieldProps('pf.maritalStatus')}

Answer (score 0):

```
const [age,setAge] = React.useState();
function handleChange(e){
   setAge(e.currentTarget.value);
}
return(
   <FormControl fullWidth>
     <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
        id="demo-simple-select"
        value={age}
        label="Age"
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the efforts, but i am not looking for the logic portion as you answered here, where as i am looking for the UI solution which is causing this issue

Comment: Implement this piece of code and see if it is breaking the UI or not, if not then it might be the problem with your component code and also defaultValue attribute value will remain same, so use value attribute instead.